# Laravel 5.3 Intervention/image NotReadableException using images from urls

Tags: php, exception

How do I deal with the following error so that my script doesn't stop working when the **exception occurs:**

> NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 302: Image source not
>   readable

I've tried using the following ($file is the url of the image):

```
// Return false if error
try
{
    $img = Image::make($file);
}
catch(NotReadableException $e)
{
    return false;
}
```

This doesn't seem to catch the exception and return false. What else can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need the full namespaced exception in  the catch area or add the use statement for that exception at the top of the file

Comment: So something like catch(Intervention\Image\Facades\Image NotReadableException $e) ?

Comment: No, don't use the facade - the namespace is Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException

Comment: Thanks. Just found it as you posted your reply ;)

Comment: Busy testing. Once I know it's working I'll accept you answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add `Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException`:

```
use Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException;

try {
    //
} catch(NotReadableException $e) {
    //
}
```