# Laravel ckeditor gives error while uploading image

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

While uploading image, I got an error :

> "NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 335: Image source not readable"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 Intervention/image NotReadableException using images from urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019973/laravel-5-3-intervention-image-notreadableexception-using-images-from-urls)

Comment: Can you show us the code where yu make the image ?

Comment: Now that error is gone. Now it says that "file uploaded successfully" but the file is not getting stored on the server. The Image::make()->save() gives "OK"